# URL Hack - Prepopulate custom field of a custom object not working

Tags: apex

I have a question regarding prepopulating a custom field (Id : 00H280000073992) in a custom object (ContactDetail). 
I used the [URL hack](http://www.forcewizard.com/blog/url-hack-prepopulate-lookup-fields-parent-data) tip, but doesn't work for me.

It works when I change the URL and remove the prefix CF : The custom field gets populated.

However, the button syntax doesn't recognize the Id without the prefix CF, and I got this `Error: Syntax error. Missing field name`.

For example :

```
{!URLFOR($Action.ContactDetail.New, null, [00H280000073992='test'])}
```

On the other hand, when I prefix with CF, the syntax is correct, the field is not populated.

For example :

```
{!URLFOR($Action.ContactDetail.New, null, [CF00H280000073992='test'])}
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$Action.ContactDetail__c.New` ?

Comment: @crop1645 You're right, it must be ContactDetail__c, but is not resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution :

```
{!URLFOR($Action.ContactDetail__c.New, null, ["00H280000073992"='test'])}
```

Comment: note that if this is a new custom field in the sandbox, when you deploy it to PROD it will not have the same ID and the URL hack will fail